# Russian characters not showing up correctly in MFC unicode list box

Tags: unicode, mfc, localization

I have an MFC application compiled with MBCS set.

I have created a unicode list box on a regular MBCS dialog using the following code:

```
DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL;
hLangListBox =  CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, //extended styles
              _T(L"listbox"),                //control 'class' name
              L"Language",              //control caption
              dwStyle,                      //control style 
              10,                      //position: left
              10,                       //position: top
              200,                     //width
              100,                    //height
              GetSafeHwnd(),         //parent window handle
              //control's ID
              reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(static_cast<INT_PTR>(ID_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH+20)),
              AfxGetInstanceHandle(),                        //application instance
              0);
```

When I inspect this dialog using Spy++ I see my Window Proc: has (Unicode) so I believe it is being created correctly.

I am populating the listbox with one of the following commands depending on if I have the data in a unicode string or a regular string

```
CStringW m_LanguageNames[MAX_LANG];

CString sFilename;

....

::SendMessageW(hLangListBox,LB_INSERTSTRING ,nMenuPos,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(theApp.m_LanguageNames[i].GetBuffer()));

::SendMessage(hLangListBox,LB_INSERTSTRING ,nMenuPos,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(sFileName.GetBuffer()));
```

Things look ok for most entries,

I can see

Chinese: 中文（简体）

French: Française

Japanese: 日本

but Russian looks like a P followed by a bunch of bars (P||||||), not Pусский.  When I look at the contents of the CStringW in Visual Studio I do see the correct text.

Why can I see the other languages correctly and not russian?  I am running on Windows 7 ultimate and compiling with Visual Studio 10

**Edit**

If I change my system locale to Russian I can see the russian characters fine.  However, the ç in Française does not appear correct.

I thought unicode strings were independent of the system locale.  Is that correct?

To populate my unicode CStringW I am doing:

```
CA2W tmp_wide(po.msgstr,CodePage);
m_LanguageNames[i] = tmp_wide;
```

where po.msgstr is a CString that was read in from a file.  In this case, CodePage is set to 1251

If I inspect the variables in Visual Studio it appears that the conversion is happening correctly.

It appears that my unicode list box can display unicode characters from a MBCS such as Chinese fine, but that it can't display unicode characters from a SBCS that is different from my current code page.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why is your app compiled with MCBS when you're using Unicode? Why did you not compile it as a Unicode app?

Comment: At this stage it breaks too many things. This is a first step.

Comment: Well, odd that you get a Unicode window.  You compile with MBCS but use the Unicode version of MFC?  That could have some interesting repercussions.

Comment: As far as I know I am not using the unicode version of MFC.

Comment: Are you using SendMessage or SendMessageW for your Russian text?

Comment: Jon, not stritly an answer, but you may look at my Language Menu CP article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/LanguageMenu.aspx
The code supports both ANSI and Unicode apps

Comment: Look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742882/display-arabic-unicode-in-mfc-view?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, solved after a long time.
In my case the default font of dialog is set to "**MS Sans Serif**", just change to use the more recent font "**Microsoft Sans Serif**" and everything is resolved!

Comment: This code snipet solved font problem , at least for me:

    CFont font;
 if (font.CreatePointFont(100, _T("Microsoft Sans Serif")))
  dlg->SetFont(&font);

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved this yet, but I think it is likely this is a font issue.  I'm not going any farther with this, but the next step would be to have an owner drawn list box and specify an appropriate font for each language