# Display Arabic/ Unicode in MFC View

Tags: unicode, mfc

I am trying to display a simple Unicode string in an MFC view class. The problem can be simplified to the following code

```
CString arabic (_T("مرحبا العالم"));
pDC->TextOutW (50, 50, arabic);
```

The problem is that the MFC window displays bars instead of the Arabic characters as shown in the screenshot below. Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

[image: First attempt to display Arabic]

I am using VS 2003 if that matters.

EDIT: When I have selected a font object in the device context, the behaviour of the application changes but it's still not correct; it displays the following characters as if I am using the wrong codepage:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the selected font does not have the chars available.

You have to select a font that has the glyphs you need into the device context.

something like this maybe:

```
CFont font;
font->CreateFont(16,0,0,0,400,FALSE,FALSE,0,ANSI_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_SWISS,
        "Tahoma");
pDC->SelectObject(font);
```

Comment: Yes, the font seemed to be missing but now it seems that there is some problem with the code page; please see the EDIT part of the question. It's weird because I am using Unicode and code page should be irrelevant.

Comment: do you compile your project with UNICODE defined? If not, you have to at least compile it with MBCS defined, otherwise your app can't handle such unicode chars correctly, no matter what codepage you use

Comment: OK. This got fixed by saving the .cpp file containing the string literal with encoding: UTF-8 with signature. The other option I had been using, UTF-8 without signature, didn't work!